# Python Eve: TypeError when I send PATCH and DELETE request

Tags: python, typeerror, eve

I'm making a REST API using Eve. Eve is running on Nginx and uwsgi on a Docker container.

**Python version**: 3.6.5

**Eve**: 0.8

**Eve-SQLAlchemy**: 0.5.0

When I send a GET request for resources and items, there's no problem.
However, when I send a PATCH or a DELETE request, the API server returns Nginx's default 50xError page.

The logs goes like this:

```
    [pid: 12|app: 0|req: 22/22] 192.168.99.1 () {46 vars in 691 bytes} [Wed Jun  6 22:55:26 2018] PATCH /maintenances/18 => generated 0 bytes in 11 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 1043, in __call__
    return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/endpoints.py", line 96, in item_endpoint
    response = patch(resource, **lookup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 297, in rate_limited
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/auth.py", line 78, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 1181, in decorated
    r = f(resource, **combined_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/methods/patch.py", line 41, in patch
    skip_validation=False, **lookup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/methods/patch.py", line 134, in patch_internal
    original = get_document(resource, concurrency_check, **lookup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 80, in get_document
    **lookup)
TypeError: find_one() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

When I delete authentication from the request, the server returns "Please provide proper credentials," but when I delete "If-Match" header from the request, the server returns this error.
(So it may be possible that some process existing between authentication and etag validation is the cause of this error.

Comment: Do you have any update or delete event hooks for the resource?

Comment: No, but I'm using Eve-SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

It's almost surely related to a version incompatibility between Eve and Eve-SQLAlchemy. **Eve-SQLAlchemy 0.5 only supports Eve 0.6** and there is currently no version available supporting newer Eve versions.

This also matches the `TypeError` you see: `find_one()` is a method in the data layer, which Eve-SQLAlchemy provides. Probably the interface changed in Eve 0.7 or 0.8.

## Where to go from here

If you're using pip then `pip check` should report an error with your installation, as Eve-SQLAlchemy declares it depends on `Eve>=0.6,<0.7` (see https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/blob/586cec403daabaeab8f7cbe133275d5fcc4e4bf3/setup.py#L35).

To fix this, either remove any pinning of Eve to an incompatible version in your `setup.py` and/or `requirements.txt`, or if that does not change anything add `Eve<0.7`. Unfortunately pip is not always able to determine a set of non-contradicting versions for all your dependencies itself, so it sometimes needs guidance to do so.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I specified Eve version 0.6.4 for pip (eve==0.6.4). No TypeError and successful PATCH and DELETE requests. Thank you very much.